# MS Graph API (mail) issue with POST and scopes

Tags: post, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, angular10, scopes

Trying to get this to work and GET / Patch work just fine, but POST gives me HTTP STATUS 400 and 403. Must be something with scopes. In Azure AD I have set the following scopes:

```
Mail.ReadWrite (Delegated)
Mail.ReadWrite (Application)
Mail.Send Delegated)
Mail.Send (Application)
```

So, signing in works just fine, getting / patching messages as well. Only POST doesnt seem to work.
See code for exact error messages.

Angular10

App.module

```
export function MSALInstanceFactory(): IPublicClientApplication {
      return new PublicClientApplication({
        auth: {
          clientId: 'xxxx',
          authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/',
          redirectUri: '/',
          postLogoutRedirectUri: '/#/login'
        },
        cache: {
          cacheLocation: BrowserCacheLocation.LocalStorage,
          storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE, // set to true for IE 11
        },
        system: {
          loggerOptions: {
            loggerCallback,
            logLevel: LogLevel.Info,
            piiLoggingEnabled: false
          }
        }
      });
    }

    export function MSALInterceptorConfigFactory(): MsalInterceptorConfiguration {
      const protectedResourceMap = new Map<string, Array<string>>();
      protectedResourceMap.set('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', ['user.read', 'mail.readWrite', 'email']);
      // also tried these scopes .. 
      // protectedResourceMap.set('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0', ['user.read', 'mail.readWrite', 'email']);
      // protectedResourceMap.set('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/query', ['user.read', 'mail.readWrite', 'email']);
      // protectedResourceMap.set('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/search/query', ['user.read', 'mail.readWrite', 'email']);

      return {
        interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
        protectedResourceMap
      };
    }

    export function MSALGuardConfigFactory(): MsalGuardConfiguration {
      return { interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect };
    }

@NgModule({
    imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      // etc..
    ],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    providers: [
      NgEventBus,
      ChhServices,
      SynclogService,
      AppService,
      AuthService,
      GapiServices,
      {
        provide: ErrorHandler,
        useClass: ErrorService,
      },
      {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: MsalInterceptor,
        multi: true
      },
      {
        provide: MSAL_INSTANCE,
        useFactory: MSALInstanceFactory
      },
      {
        provide: MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG,
        useFactory: MSALGuardConfigFactory
      },
      {
        provide: MSAL_INTERCEPTOR_CONFIG,
        useFactory: MSALInterceptorConfigFactory
      },
      MsalService,
      MsalGuard,
      MsalBroadcastService
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  })
  export class AppModule { }
```

Auth.service

```
signIn() {
    console.log('AuthService::signIn');
    this.msalService.loginPopup().subscribe((result) => {
        this.accessToken = result['accessToken'];
        console.log('authority', result, this.accessToken);
    });
}

testGraphApi() {

    // 200 OK
    const apiGet = this.httpClient.get(`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/`).subscribe((data) => {
        console.log('get', '/me/messages', data);
    });

    const categories: any[] = ['custom'];
    const body = {
        subject: '2320, with tags',
        flag: { flagStatus: 'flagged' }, // notFlagged
        categories,
        body: {
            contentType: 'html',
            content: 'lalala'
        },
        inferenceClassification: 'other'
    };

    const id = 'AQMkADAwATM3ZmYAZS0zOTkANy02MTAwAC0wMAItMDAKAEYAAAM_TfJTK-tISYhjZdaCkkbgBwCPpkVcscQ9QJF-EDzB8h_oAAACAQwAAACPpkVcscQ9QJF-EDzB8h_oAAACHbIAAAA=';

    // 200 OK
    const apiPatch = this.httpClient.patch(`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/${id}`, body).subscribe((data) => {
        console.log('patch', '/me/messages', data);
    });

    const bodySendMail = {
        'message': {
            'subject': 'Meet for lunch?',
            'body': {
                'contentType': 'Text',
                'content': 'The new cafeteria is open.'
            },
            // etc..
        }
    }

    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.accessToken}` });

    // 403 Forbidden
    // "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
    // "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",
    const apiSendMail = this.httpClient.post(`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendMail`, bodySendMail, { headers }).subscribe((data) => {
        console.log('post', '/me/sendMail', data);
    });

    const bodySearch = {
        'requests': [
            {
                'entityTypes': [
                    'message'
                ],
                'query': {
                    'queryString': 'ref:6019d6bf1ce3425fb833559e'
                },
                'from': 0,
                'size': 5
            }
        ]
    }

    // 400 Bad Request
    // "code": "AuthenticationError",
    // "message": "Error authenticating with resource",
    const apiSearch = this.httpClient.post(`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/search/query`, bodySearch, { headers }).subscribe((data) => {
        console.log('post', '/search/query', data);
    });
}
```

Comment: I've tried the api of '/me/sendMail' and '/search/query', and I can both get correct response. For your 403 error, I think you could try to use '/users/{user id}' to replace '/me' to rule out the error of wrong flow. By the way it's more likely that the access token you used to send mail has no correct scope and I really didn't find the scope '**Mail.Send**' in your code. For 400 error, I've copied your request body json object to my request and it did work, so I think it may also result from error access token. I used ropc flow which uses  user id and password to generate token.

Comment: Does the above helped?

Comment: @tiny-wa
1. ROPC flow doesn't seem suitable for my app purpose, to serve a larger anonymous audience, how ever, for testing purposes its worth the try.
2. [mail.send] is added to the scope and now that works, so thanks :-) overlooked that one.
3. seems like the path /search/query isnt accepted in combi with my token, yes.. feels like i'm almost there since post and patch is working with the /me path. Still looking into this.

Comment: @SanJayFalcon Thanks for your response, and upon the 400 error, I think you should make sure you used a work or school account with Delegated permission, it's defined in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/search-query?view=graph-rest-1.0#permissions) that only this can be supported and if you used a personal account, it may leads to 400 error.

Comment: Yes only delegated permission is supported with work/school account. If you're using application scenario, then it won't be supported. Being said that i see that you're calling /me endpoint, so its not application scenario. So just make sure which account (personal/work&school) you're using...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> // 403 Forbidden
> // "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
> // "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."
> ```

[Send mail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) API needs `Mail.Send` permission. When requesting `/me` endpoint which bases the current signed-in user, it should have the **delegated permission**.

So you need to add `Mail.Send` of delegated permission in the portal and add it in your code.

> ```
> // 400 Bad Request
> // "code": "AuthenticationError",
> // "message": "Error authenticating with resource"
> ```

[searchEntity: query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/search-query?view=graph-rest-1.0) API needs the `Mail.ReadWrite` delegated permission. This api only supports "work or school account". A work account typically uses an organization’s custom domain name or company name, such as "jon@contoso.com" or "xxx@yourTenantName.onmicrosoft.com".

[image]

You could test to request the api in [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#).